# Creating a list of past 5 dates from given date in string format in Python

Tags: python, string, date

I have a string which contains a date. I need to create a list with previous 5 dates including the given date in python.

Example:

```
date = ['09-26-2016']

dates = ['09-21-2016','09-22-2016','09-23-2016','09-24-2016','09-25-2016','09-26-2016']
```

I need to create dates given date as input. The input is in string format.

Comment: You can't use strings the same way you would use dates.  You have to convert them *first*.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Its not homework. I am using this for my current project where I need to check certain conditions for previous dates. I decided not to give much information as it is not very relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `datetime` to parse the strings into dates and calculate `timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
d='09-24-2016'
d1=datetime.strptime(d, '%m-%d-%Y')
[(d1-timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for i in range(6,0,-1)]
['09-20-2016','09-21-2016', '09-22-2016', '09-23-2016', '09-24-2016', '09-25-2016']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date = ['09-26-2016']
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date[0], '%m-%d-%Y')

dates=[]

dates.append(date_time_obj)

for i in range(0,4):
    print(i)
    j=i+1
    print(j)
    dates_list= date_time_obj.date() - timedelta(days=j)
    dates.append(dates_list)

print(dates)
```